# angularjs show/hide tabs

Tags: angularjs

Here i am displaying tabs from array using angularjs and bootstrap.
What i want is when i click on particular tab it should display content of that tab only.

i.e(**When i click on dynamic-2 i want to display content of dynamic 2 and hide the content of dynamic-1 and dynamic-3 tab**)

Right now i am getting content of all tabs on clicking.

**js file**

```
 var items=[
                          {
                                Name:"tab1",
                                id:1,
                                content:"FirstTab",
                                title:"Dynamic-1",
                                templateUrl:"first.html"

                               },

                               {
                                Name:"tab2",
                                id:2,
                                content:"SecondTab",
                                title:"Dynamic-2",
                                templateUrl:"second.html"


                              },

                               {
                                Name:"tab3",
                                id:3,
                                content:"ThirdTab",
                                title:"Dynamic-3",
                                templateUrl:"third.html"
                              }
                       ];

 }]);
```

**html file**

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li  ng-repeat="l in list" > 

                <a href="#firsttab" ng-click="tab = 1"  data-toggle="tab" >
            {{l.title}} </a>

                <div class="tab-content" >
                     <div id="firsttab" ng-click="tab = 1" ng-
                                                show="tab===1">
                    Id: {{l.id}} <br> 
                     Name: {{l.Name}} <br>
                     Content: {{l.content}} <br>
                     TemplateFile: <div ng-include="l.templateUrl"></div>
                </div>

 </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: Hi, you can pass arguments when you $broadcast: $rootScope.$broadcast('scanner-started', { any: {} }); And then receive them:  $scope.$on('scanner-started', function(event, args) {

    var anyThing = args.any;
    // do what you want to do
});

Comment: Documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on

Answer (score 1):

**model.js**(Just change the code of this file with the code I have written below. It will give you desired result) 
We have to provide delay to broadcast to make it work.

```
define(['jquery','ocLazyLoad','cssinjector'], function() {
    var app=angular.module('App', ['angular.css.injector','oc.lazyLoad']);
    app.controller('mycontroller', ['$scope','$ocLazyLoad','cssInjector','$rootScope','$timeout',
    function($scope,$ocLazyLoad,cssInjector,$rootScope,$timeout) {

            alert("modal-loaded");

             $ocLazyLoad.load("http://localhost:8080/tabs/js/modal1.js")
             .then(function(){
                alert("modal1 loaded");
                $scope.view="http://localhost:8080/tabs/view.html";
                cssInjector.add("http://localhost:8080/tabs/style.css");
        });


            // ARRAY

                var items=[
                              {
                                    Name:"tab1",
                                    id:1
                                   },

                                   {
                                    Name:"tab2",
                                    id:2
                                  },

                                   {
                                    Name:"tab3",
                                    id:3
                                  }
                           ];

                     $timeout(function(){
                         $rootScope.$broadcast('itmObj', items);
               },0);   

     }]);




       angular.element(function() {
       angular.bootstrap(document, ['App']);
        });         
     });
```

Comment: Bad Answer even if it worked. Its bad to introduce unwanted timeouts. The broadcast is not working as the modal controller is not initialized and is not in context when the broadcast is invoked. it is true that we have to invoke broadcast after view/modalcontroler is loaded. but not using a timeout.

Comment: @sachin for that inject $timeout

Comment: try the current one

Comment: sorry forgot to inject '$rootScope' and '$timeout'

Answer (score 0):

If you broadcast like this in parent controller

```
$scope.$broadcast('itmObj',{ itemsArray: items});
```

Then you can use the on-catch in child controller like
and you eill have the `items` array in args.itemsArray

```
$scope.$on('itmObj', function (event, args) {
 var x = args.itemsArray; // args.itemsArray is your items from parentcontroller
 });
```

Comment: i did that but still not able to display array.

Comment: is the on function hit?

Comment: nope..when i console.log(items) under broadcast it gets displayed but when i try to do the same under $on it doesn't show anything.

Comment: can u put a  debugger inside $on callback-function and check if that is hit sometime?

Comment: is your  alert("In modal Controller"); alert shown?

Comment: and is that  $on callback function hit?

Comment: i have attached my debug image at the end of my code..you can see that

Comment: put the debugger on the next line: console.log(data);

Comment: that means your broadcast is not hitting $on. maybe we can connect on skype after sometime

Comment: yeah sure after my working hours..tll then if you come up with any solution then do comment..

Comment: I suppose this happens bcoz u dont have the modalController context when you are broadcasting the itmObj; try putting the broadcast inside a function and call the function only after the view is shown. it wont work when modalController context is  absent

Comment: i am getting the array in console when i use click function..i have edited my code you can look into that

Comment: click function to invoke broadcast ryt??

Comment: yeah i have edited it..i tried click function and it's working..but when i remove the function i don't get anything

Comment: and that is because when u click, the dom is loaded well and so the 'view' is loaded and the modalController context is ready. And after that is when you click and invoke the $broadcast. and when u do that $on in modalController is ready

Comment: To wrap it up, $broadcast only when $on is ready and avaliable

Comment: yeah i got that..but i want array to display on load not on click..that's the issue here

Comment: how is your array initialised? is it from some api?

Comment: $broadcast is not intended for this purpose. I mean' to show on load'. you can  easlily set the array in modalController rather than appController.

Comment: it's about holding and capturing the array using broadcast and on..as i am doing that...i want to hold my array in modal.js and capture that whole array in my modal1.js and view that array using ng-repeat in view.htm this is my flow this is what i want to do...and my array is in modal.js only

Comment: yeah i am walking through it...some closing bracket errors are there.

Comment: hey do you know how can i use $defer in this to get my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to add a promise on lazyloading the modalController and modal view will look like this
**Modal.js**

```
    define(['jquery','ocLazyLoad','cssinjector'], function() {
    var app=angular.module('App', ['angular.css.injector','oc.lazyLoad']);
    app.controller('mycontroller', ['$scope','$ocLazyLoad','cssInjector',
    function($scope,$ocLazyLoad,cssInjector) {

            alert("modal-loaded");
            // ARRAY
            var items=[{
                           Name:"tab1",
                           id:1
                       },{
                           Name:"tab2",
                           id:2
                       },{
                           Name:"tab3",
                           id:3
                       }];

            var lazyLoadModal1 = function(){
                 var deferred = $q.defer();
                 $ocLazyLoad.load("http://localhost:8080/tabs/js/modal1.js")
                 .then(function(){
                     alert("modal1 loaded");
                     $scope.view="http://localhost:8080/tabs/view.html";
                     cssInjector.add("http://localhost:8080/tabs/style.css");

                     deferred.resolve();
                  },function(){
                     deferred.reject();
                  });  
                return deferred.promise;
           };
           var init = (function(){
                 lazyLoadModal1().then(function(){
                    $scope.$broadcast('itmObj', {item:items});
                 });
           })();
     }]);
```

**View.html**

```
<div ng-controller="modalcontroller">
    <div ng-repeat="vm in itemsArray">
     <p>{{vm.Name}}</p>
     <p>{{vm.id}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Modal1.js**

```
angular.module('App', ['angular.css.injector','oc.lazyLoad'])
 .controller("modalcontroller", ['$scope','$ocLazyLoad','cssInjector',
 function($scope,$ocLazyLoad,cssInjector){

        alert("In modal Controller");

        $scope.$on("broadcast-started", function (event, data){
                $scope.itemsArray=data.item;
                console.log($scope.itemsArray);
    });

 }]);
```

Comment: to use $defer, is your cssInjector.add, a library

Comment: now it's showing in console..used emit broadcast and on together

Comment: Hey how can display it using ng-repeat?  Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: sachin. now can you vote both of my answers and accept this one as answer

Comment: i din't used the above code bro..i made changes in mine..above code was displaying nothing in console

Comment: used emit along with broadcast and on

Comment: emit is for child to parent and broadcast is for parent to child

Comment: ok.. so u have a set of bad code. Take it to your app. Your reviewer will love it